# Sort an eloquent query based on the field of a nested model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this eloquent query that brings me 10 reports in a paginated manner with their respective transactions and contracts

```
            $reports = Report::with([
                "transaccions",
                "status_report",
                "contracts",
            ])
                ->where(function ($query) use ($filter, $dates, $type_report, $dataservice) {
                    $query
                        ->where("type_report", ($dataservice == 'true' ? '<>' : '='), $type_report)
                        ->whereBetween("created_at", [$dates[0], $fechas[count($dates) - 1]])
                        ->whereHas('status_report', function ($q) {
                            $q->whereIn("status", ["VERIFYED"]);
                        })
                        ->where(function ($query) use ($filter) {
                            $query->where("id", "like", '%' . $filter . '%')
                                ->orWhereHas('contracts', function ($query) use ($filter) {
                                    $query->where('contract', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')
                                        ->orWhereHas("rif", function ($query) use ($filter) {
                                            $query->where("rif", 'like', '%' . $filter . '%');
                                        })
                                        ->orWhere("name", 'like', '%' . $filter . '%');
                                })->orWhereHas('transaccions', function ($query) use ($filter) {
                                    $query->where('ref', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%')
                                        ->orWhere('amount', 'like', '%' . $filter . '%');
                                });
                        });
                })
                ->paginate($length);
```

This query shows a result that is processed in another function and shows something like this

```
        {
            "id": 45751,
            "status": "VERIFYED",
            "type_report": "MENSUALITY",
            "nota": "",
            "transaccions": [
                {
                    "id": 46358,
                    "ref": "22380011359",
                    "voucher": false
                }
            ],
            "total": "1,28",
            "contracts": [
                {
                    "name": "PERSON",
                    "contract": "123456",
                    "rif": "1122334455",
                    "status": "ACTIVE"
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2022-08-26 14:18:00"
        },
```

These results are displayed in a table and I would like to be able to sort the results based on transactions.amount, contracts.contract (or any other field from the nested models)
but I can't find the way to do it, I know that you can order the nested models in this way:

```
             "transaccions" => function ($query) use ($order_by, $order) {
                    $query->orderBy($order_by, $order);
                },
```

but I need is to sort all the results, because that only sorts me the nested objects, thanks.

Comment: You'd have to `join()` the tables; `with()` doesn't perform any kind of `JOIN ...` syntax, so you can't target `transactions.amount`.

Comment: yes, that's what I did, I changed the query to join and I was able to do this `>groupBy($order_by, "report.id")->orderBy($order_by, $order)` 
But now my problem is when I order by another field that is not `report.id`, such as `contracts.contract` it repeats the records

Comment: Yup, which can happen when using both `->join()` and `->with()`, or multiple joins, etc. You'll have to debug your final query and determine which join methods or `select` statements to use to get the records you need (and I'm not an SQL expert, so I personally can't assist much with that)

Comment: @MarcelSalazar if you are sorting the query with a nested values using `join`, then I see why it duplicates some of the records. As I suppose one `report` can have multiple `transactions` and `contracts`. So for example if you sort using `contracts` values, one `report` can have contracts `10` and `12`. And another `report` can have contract `11`. So if you sort that, you will have duplicated first `report` - before and after the second `report`. Could you show how the resulting table looks like and what values are shown there?

Comment: @Lothric I don't know how to show you the result here, but if I filter by a specific `report ` number that has 5 associated `contracts` and I order by `contract` , the result is that the same report is repeated 5 times

Comment: @MarcelSalazar sure it repeats since SQL has no nested arrays. You can upload an image or just tell what your table looks like, what values from database are going to your table?